# My API laravel doesn't work when it run on my reactjs

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, axios, response

I got a problem, my API laravel doesn't work when it run on my reactjs. When I check, i got failed response data. But,it work fine in postman. Here's my code

This is in reactjs :
[This code in ReactJs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5LHj.png)

and this is in laravel API : 
[this code in laravel API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga9Hw.png)

i use axios to get response from my API, and i have already set my cors before in my Laravel, just one function can't get response.

here the respons :

[response in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oN1R.png)

[response in console log react when use chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Cov.png)

[response in network google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS8Zz.png)

I already try to set up cors again and try to change method put to get and put to post, and still doesnt work. I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: please copy-paste the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to connect with jquery or javascript XMLHttpRequest to make sure where is the problem